# How to present the result of a dynamic pivot request in SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have a dynamic pivot request I would like to present in a report of Reporting Services.

As it is dynamic, the number of columns of the result is variable (as is the name of the columns). How could I create a report showing a table handling this variable number of columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the Matrix control to pivot the results in the report instead of in the query. This way you don't have to use any custom solution.

Comment: In fact, I also had to add many static columns on the left of my dynamics columns, and so, I felt that I needed to make a join on the result of my pivot request before handing it to reporting services. I finally managed a solution, but it is a bit of a hack : I used a matrix control, and then, in the left column, I splitted the field in as many textboxes as necessary, where I showed the different fields I needed. Then, formated the top left cell to simulate that it is multiple table headers.

Comment: What I usually do is insert the static columns in the same field as my dynamic columns in my query and have everything dynamic. This way your matrix is easier to maintain :). Glad it works

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement a dynamic report definition file.  Here is a link that will help you get started.  It is a VS Project that dynamically creates a RDLC file with a table, via a datatable.  I used it as the base of my current report system.

[C# Version](http://gotreportviewer.com/DynamicTable.zip)

[VB.NET Version](http://gotreportviewer.com/DynamicTableVB.zip)

If you have any questions about this, let me know.  I've been generating RDLC files for quite a while now, and encountered pretty much every issue you could think of  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am completely stuck on this. I must admit I would have preferred a solution that would not force me to learn c#, but thanks anyway.